# Allow approval of suggested edits by just a single person when inside a question page

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

So, it makes sense that if someone is just going through the suggested edits queue, they may not be the most familiar with the specific technology or the details of the questions and may make a mistake as to whether to approve/reject something. Requiring two votes makes sense in that context.

But in the context of a particular post, when you click on `edit (0)` (for example) below that question, it seems the approve/reject should be immediate and only require one person. If you're clicking on that edit link from within the question page, you're probably familiar with the technology (or you wouldn't be looking at the question far enough to see an edit), and you've already read and understand the question. So you are likely to be in a position to evaluate the edit more accurately than if it was just some random question you encountered in the suggested edits queue.

The specific use case I encountered was a badly formatted post, with non-formatted code blocks. I was going to edit it to add code blocks, but someone else without edit privs beat me to it, adding a suggested edit. I went to approve it, but it still required approval of one more person to take effect. In the mean time, the post was still sitting there badly formatted.

Comment: There is already a workaround for this as animuson suggests: edit more. You can hit "improve" and even add a space character if no other editing is needed. Despite that cheesy hack, the problem you cite is relevant but the solution I disagree with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not always the case though. I visit questions on topics that I have no experience in just for the sake of viewing it. The title looked interesting and I clicked on it. Even if that condition were true, I still don't see it as an excuse to bypass the approval-by-two process.

If you need to expedite an approval, find something else that is wrong and improve the post to add to it. The suggested edit is immediately approved and your additional contributions are added on top of it.

Comment: But if you are just casually browsing for interesting questions, are you going to even click on the "edit" link if there is a suggestion in the queue?

Comment: @Ben: Why wouldn't I? If I notice there's a pending edit, sure, I'll look at it.

Comment: Also, if I'm *certain* the edit is correct (because it's the edit I was going to do myself), seems like it's silly that I'd have to work around it by introducing my own separate improvement.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? If you're not familiar enough with the question or technology to evaluate an edit, why would you?

Comment: @Ben: A majority of edits can be accurately approved/rejected without any knowledge of the subject whatsoever. If I see it is an edit that is specific to the subject that I can't accurately give an opinion on, then I don't vote on it. However, that's not any different from what I would do in the suggested edits panel.

Comment: Okay, I guess my assumption about who is likely to click "edit" from within a question page may be false.